# Modifying Outlook E-Mail Signature in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, outlook

Is it possible to change and set the email signature in windows phone 7 outlook via Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. API for changing system settings is practically nonexistent.

Comment: Too bad, managing email signatures is important for us. Hoping that Win 8 Phone introduces the necessary API.